# count sublists that contain a particular element and output the count in python

Tags: python, list, count

I'm looking to write a function that outputs the count of sublists that contain a particular element.

```
>>res = count_doc_frequencies([['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a']])
>>res['a']
3
>>res['b']
2
```

Here in our case, 'a' occurs in all three sublists and hence the output is 3, while 'b' happens to occur only in sublist one and sublist two and thus the output is 2

can anyone help me here ?

Answer (score 2):

If the nesting is always one level deep, then using the `list.count()` method will be fastest:

```
lst = [['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a']]
print sum(sublst.count('a') for sublst in lst)
```

if you want to count the number of sub-lists that contain an element then:

```
print sum('a' in sublst for sublst in lst)
```

(this takes advantage of the fact that `Bool` is a subclass of `int`).

Comment: I want to count the occurrences of all the elements and then display the count on my call as i've displayed in my example output above, can you suggest changes according to that ?

Comment: To get exactly that, just use @ozgur's solution as is.

Comment: to count the number of sublists that contain a particular element , not just 'a' what should i do ? to get an output as i've mentioned above what changes do i have to make in your code ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really want the number of *occurrence* of an item, something like that, maybe:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a']]
>>> sum(1 for i in itertools.chain(*l) if i == 'a')
4
```

---

If you only need the number of sublist containing the item:

```
>>> sum(1 for i in l if 'a' in l)
3
```

Comment: how to count and display the count of sublists that contain a specific element in them..@Sylvain Leroux

Answer (score 0):

```
a=sum(x in i for i in l)
print(a)
```